# When i update color in OBJ error occurred in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I have updated dynamically in OBJ. I got error in **"TypeError: child.material.color is undefined"**.  Why this error occurred What was the mistake in my code.

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
loader.load( file, function ( object ) { 
  object.traverse( function ( child ) {
    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
     // child.material.ambient.setHex(0xFF0000);

     if(object_color!=""){

      //alert("object color entere");

      object_color=object_color.replace('#', '')
      child.material.color.setHex("0x"+object_color);
    }
    }
  } );
```

Comment: Do you have the .mtl (material) file for that .obj file?

Comment: yes i have material file

Comment: But its possible to change color dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code not problem code working correctly, Problem is have a obj. I have checked valid obj, Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
child.material.color
```

This is the diffuse color of the geometry. In case of the Obj file, this color will be defined for a material in the corresponding .mtl file. If you dont have that .mtl file or if the material your geometry uses does not have diffuse color defined in the .mtl file, you could experience the problem you are facing.

You can solve this problem by using following code -

```
if(child.material.color)
    child.material.color.setHex("0x"+object_color);
else
    child.material.color = new THREE.Color("0x"+object_color);
```

Comment: I have tested above code. enter in else part, But color not yet applied.

Comment: `"0x"+object_color` you need to convert from string to hex value.

Comment: I have check the code not a problem , Obj have a problem